# libstk.a undefined symbol for architecture x86_64 (or i386)

Tags: xcode, x86-64, toolkit, i386, synthesis

I try to use the library libstk.a (from The Synthesis ToolKit in C++ (STK))in a XCode 4.5.1 application project to build for Standard(32/64 bit Intel) architectures.
I just drop the file libstk.a and stk.h into my project.

First I made the library of stk-4.4.4 following the instructions given in the doc of stk (./configure with --with-core and --enable-debug) and then make in the src directory. It gives the libstk.a file without errors.
In the xcode project, no syntax error, but link errors : undefined symbol for architecture x86_64 for different methods (maybe all) + the same for i386
It looks like libstk.a was not build for i386 or x86_64.

I used command lines to make the library and i am not familiar with this. How can I ensure that the library will be build for i386 and i86_64 archs ? Do I have to do something different to include the library in my project than just drop it in the files list ? I need help !

Answer (score 0):

Use `-arch i386` or `-arch x86_64` gcc option..